# GET facebook group feed on graph 2.8

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with facebook graph api in accessing user group.

If i access directly with this: 
https://graph.facebook.com/fb_id/groups?access_token=token

I can access and retrieve group that i manage only.

other group i join as member not showing on graph

i have already tried

```
try {$response = $fb->get('/me/$groupid', $pageAccessToken);}
```

`catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {`

```
echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
```

the result is same..
May I know what went wrong here?

Comment: are those other groups closed or secret?

Comment: Why would you use a page access token for that request? When you use a page token, `/me` resolves to the id of the page the token is for. ut pages don’t have groups ...

Comment: CBroe its just variable.. I use user token

Comment: Luschn i cant get all group that i m joined as member.. Its just show group that i m as admin..

Comment: i guess that is intended, so the group feed of closed/private groups does not just show up somewhere else.

Comment: how to resolve this?